# Is there a performance penalty returning an int in a method that return a primitive double?

Tags: java

When you have a method that return a primitive double and you return an int value a [Widening Primitive Conversion happens](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

When we have a case like:

example 1:

```
double getSomething() {
   if (someConditon()) {
        return 0;
   }
   return someDoubleValue;
}
```

example 2:

```
double getSomething() {
   if (someConditon()) {
        return 0.0d;
   }
   return someDoubleValue;
}
```

Is there a performance penalty when you return an int value (example 1) instead of a double value (example 2) ?

If yes, the good practice is return the value with the accurate type. So example 2 that could return `0.0d` instead of `0` ?

Comment: It does not make a difference *technically* (I'm pretty sure that the resulting byte code will be the same). However, for clarity, it should be `0.0` (as I think `0.` looks plain ugly and incomplete...)

Comment: I would even go as far as `0.0d` to explicitly show I'm using a double, not a float. But that's a personal choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter as long as the type of literal you type *can* be silently converted to double. The compiler will do the conversion at compile time, resulting in identical byte code for *all* of these (note even the weirder ones like *long* and *char*):

```
public class ReturnDouble {

    static double returnF() {
        return 0F;
    }

    static double returnD() {
        return 0D;
    }

    static double returnI() {
        return 0;
    }

    static double returnL() {
        return 0L;
    }

    static double returnS() {
        return (short) 0;
    }

    static double returnC() {
        return '\0';
    }

}
```

You can verify this by disassembling the class using the javap utility from the JDK. The disassembly output is:

```
public class ReturnDouble {
  public ReturnDouble();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  static double returnF();
    Code:
       0: dconst_0
       1: dreturn

  static double returnD();
    Code:
       0: dconst_0
       1: dreturn

  static double returnI();
    Code:
       0: dconst_0
       1: dreturn

  static double returnL();
    Code:
       0: dconst_0
       1: dreturn

  static double returnS();
    Code:
       0: dconst_0
       1: dreturn

  static double returnC();
    Code:
       0: dconst_0
       1: dreturn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> the value zero returned at the ex1, is changed to a double type value.

It's because the return type of it. Since you are returning an `int` primitive conversion will happen and `int` converted to `double.`

Since the conversion is int to double  [`Widening Primitive Conversion- jls-5.1.2`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) happens

> specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> byte to short, int, long, float, or double
>
> short to int, long, float, or double
>
> char to int, long, float, or double
>
> **int to** long, float, or **double**

Answer (score 0):

Because your method declares that it will return a `double` it always needs to return a `double`. If you hardcode it, like in your examples, you can be sure that compilation will fail if types don't match and can't be converted.

**TL;DR:** Everything works in this particular case. If not, the compiler would tell you.